# Mgo-based app code structure dealing with connection pool and tcp timeouts

Tags: tcp, go, mgo

I'm curious how should I structure JSON REST API server in [Go](http://golang.org) language with [Mgo](http://labix.org/mgo) library. I have dozens of collections related with each other. I've created [the gist](https://gist.github.com/rafalsobota/7369852) with sample part of file structure in my current approach.

It works great, but from time to time I encounter downtime caused by this error: "read tcp 10.168.30.100:37288: i/o timeout". I suppose that I handle mgo connection pool inapropriately. Are there any examples showing how should I create big applications based on mgo?

Comment: Have you create any big applications in MongoDB in general? I mean may be the issue because you data model is not so good then the time spend for loading all data you need take to loong (just guest :D)

Comment: In most of time it is super fast. After server restart this problem disappear.

Comment: Are you trying to create new connection to mongodb every request (I mean cal mgo.Dial in the http handler). Maybe profiling your program will help you.

Comment: I found some reply from the mgo author himself that could interest you:
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mgo-users/iZeiKgonGDU/2w4jf0V18TgJ
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mgo-users/oVJcXKPvNbU/L4AxMFDooD8J

Comment: I have a node.js application in production with 100.000+ users, but it also struggles with timeouts, so maybe solution for this could be more universal. This server in go most of time works on request in 20-200 ms.

Comment: @nvcnvn I only create connection once on application start and use it in every http request handler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error message implies a roundtrip to the database took longer than the timeout period you defined. Just increasing that timeout should get rid of the problem, assuming you don't have any real issues that are causing the application to behave in a sluggish manner.

In general, this error doesn't imply you have any kind of scale issues, other than the fact maybe you have an increasing amount of data in some collections and certain queries may be getting too slow and need re-thinking (indexes, etc).

There's also no need to restart the application. You can either Refresh the problematic session, or Close and re-create the session in case you're using copies of a master session. The state of mgo and the pool of connections is still fine. It's just warning you that this specific session observed an issue on the wire, and so you have to acknowledge it before the session will be valid again.

As usual, also make sure to be using the latest release to avoid problems that have already been fixed, if any.

Comment: I create session once on application start and use it in every http handler, as in my gist - https://gist.github.com/rafalsobota/7369852#file-database-go-L13 . May it cause this problem? If so, can I simply refresh session after resolving http request or should I clone session for every http request and pass it to my model logic (it requires major refactoring of my code)?

Comment: When this error occures in my app it repeats multiple times and after server restart everything backs to normal behavior.

Comment: You're describing precisely the behavior I pointed out in the third paragraph. The error will not go away until you acknowledge it. One easy and good way to organize it is to Copy the master session for each handler, and defer Close it to make sure you don't have leaks. This way each new session will pick a good socket from the pool, or establish a new connection if necessary.

Comment: Thanks Gustavo. Is there any blog post how this connection pool works under the cover?. I don't think I understand everything and still have some questions. 1. Does this error mean that connection is lost and mgo doens't know about it yet and reuses it? 2. When I Close connection it doesn't back to the pool if it's broken? 3. Is it a good practise to Refresh session as soon as error occures and try again instead of return 5xx http status code?

Comment: 4. Can I use only one session in my entire application in multiple goroutines and only Refresh this global session when I detect this error? Why not? My existing queries would be killed?

Comment: There are good recent threads in the mailing list on the topic. Please move there for a more open conversation.